# ogr2ogr batch load shapefiles into geodatabase

Tags: shapefile, gdal, file-geodatabase, ogr2ogr

I'm trying to load a directory of shapefiles into a geodatabase with ogr2ogr. It works fine if I specify a single shapefile, but can't open the datasources if I specify a wildcard. Is there a wildcard I can use to import all of the shapefiles in the directory?

this works:

```
ogr2ogr -f 'FileGDB' -update -append allroads.gdb roads.shp
```

This fails and errors with:
"Unable to open datasource `roads.shp' with the following drivers."

```
ogr2ogr -f 'FileGDB' -update -append allroads.gdb *.shp
```

Comment: Might be easier to write a loop in whatever shell this is running from - is this Windows or Unix/Linux/Mac?

Comment: This is on a mac, so a loop in bash would work.

Comment: Have you tried just giving the folder instead of a shapefile? OGR should treat the folder as a data source, and each shapefile as a layer. In a test, I created a GML with all shapefiles from a folder in one line: `ogr2ogr -f GML foo.gml ./shapes/` - not sure if the FileGDB driver will work the same way...

Comment: @Spacedman - that is the ticket! worked like a charm. Will you post that as an an answer so I can mark it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OGR treats a folder as a data source with shapefiles in the folder as layers. If you add the folder using `ogr2ogr` then it will add all the shapefiles to the output data source. For example to create a GML file with one layer for every shapefile in the folder `shapes`, do:

```
ogr2ogr -f GML foo.gml ./shapes/
```

which should work for any OGR output data format, including your File GDB.

Note that it might add *any* geographic data files in `./shapes/`, so if there's KML or GML in there they might get added too.

Comment: That's great info I never heard about before. Do you know if the exact behaviour is documented somewhere?

Comment: Yes, in the shapefile driver docs http://www.gdal.org/drv_shapefile.html "Normally the OGR Shapefile driver treats a whole directory of shapefiles as a dataset, and a single shapefile within that directory as a layer."

Comment: AWESOME! very useful for my task!